# Concatenate list and for loop

Tags: python, list, for-loop, nested, concatenation

I was wondering if there was an easy way to do this:

```
kwargs = {
    'element2':[2,3,4]
    'element3':[5,6,7]
}
myList = ["element1"] + \
         ["0 1"] + \
         for key,val in kwargs.items:
            [key] + \
            [' '.join([str(val) for val in vals])]
```

This obviously results in a syntax error..
I have a workaround which is using this:

```
kwargs = {
    'element2':[2,3,4]
    'element3':[5,6,7]
}
myList = ["element1"] + \
         ["0 1"] + \
         [[key] + [' '.join([str(val) for val in vals])] for key,vals in kwargs.items()]
```

The problem is that "myList" will be a nested list, which I need to flatten afterwards...
Any idea how I can make this clean and simple?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep a similar syntax, you could add another list comprehension like so:

```
kwargs = {
    'element2':[2,3,4],
    'element3':[5,6,7]
}
myList = ["element1"] + \
         ["0 1"] + \
         [i for j in
         [[key] + [' '.join([str(val) for val in vals])] for key,vals in kwargs.items()]
         for i in j]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can append to the list in a loop

```
myList = ["element1", "0 1"]
for key, vals in kwargs.items():
    myList.append(key)
    myList.append(" ".join(map(str, vals)))
```

Comment: Sure, thanks. I was just wondering if there was a line syntax possible. Actually, I am building the list after a "return" command so it should be in one line if possible

Comment: You could probably do it with `reduce()`. I don't think a list comprehension can create more than one element per iteration.

Comment: You could use your method and then `flatten()`

Comment: @carlitador you can flatten via a nested list comp or using `itertools.chain`, but you'd be clearer with a regular loop like `for key, vals in kwargs.items(): myList.extend((key, " ".join(map(str, vals))))`